# Add values just to one column in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a `DataGridView` with 6 columns; I want the first column to display the days of the week. And the second column should display a schedule per day. But I want them to display in **vertical order**, not in horizontal way. But I can't figure out how to do it.

I have it like this:[image]

And I want it like this:[image]

Comment: I guess you mean `Rows` by the word `vertical order`

Comment: Yes. I tried using Rows.Add and the app was adding them in horizontal order (as columns)

Comment: would be a lot easier for someone to answer in my opinion if you would show your code..

Comment: That's the problem, I just don't know how to write a code for writing in a single column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to your second picture:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(9);

// for days column (1st column)
dataGridView1[0,0].Value = "Monday";
dataGridView1[0,3].Value = "Tuesday";
dataGridView1[0,6].Value = "Wednesday";

// for hours column (3rd column)
dataGridView1[2,0].Value = "7:00 - 8:00";
dataGridView1[2,1].Value = "8:00 - 9:00";
dataGridView1[2,3].Value = "7:00 - 7:50";
dataGridView1[2,4].Value = "7:50 - 8:20";
```

Basically

`dataGridView[Column index, Row index].Value` is the cell value at those coordinates

Comment: This is what I get when trying to build: "No overload for method 'this' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: Copy paste my code in your `Form1_Load` function and tell me what you get

Comment: Ah ok, now I don't get more errors, and for the third column(hour) how can I modify the code?

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss what do you mean how can you modify the code..? do you have the source code on your end..?

Comment: I mean the code that @chouaib gave me, I'm asking what should I modify in that block of code to make it work in the third column

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss, I edited my answer, you can base on it to fill your gridView as you want to do